# Kafka syncronous send vs inflight requests

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

If I send messages synchronously using -

```
producer.send(myRecord).get();
```

Am I guaranteed that messages will reach the respective partitions in the same order as they were sent?

Or do i still need to set the `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1`

(Currently the max.in.flight.requests.per.connection is set to be greater than one, so I need to be clear on this before I can suggest setting this to one, only if it's required. I have to recommend it only if it's mandatory).

My current understanding is -

```
producer.send(myRecord).get();
```

will also take care of retries. The next record will not be processed until the first one succeeds or fails after N retries. Only after the first record has failed or succeeded the second record will be processed/sent to the broker.

Comment: i understand the `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` thing. But what i don't understand is when `.send().get()` blocks the thread - no other message can be attempted to deliver (unless the same producer is being used in multiple threads, in this situation i agree with Alan.) But in a single threaded situation - just doing `.send().get()` should ensure ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, producer.send().get() should ensure ordering. The other way to ensure ordering is by setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1, which allows you to async send messages, and batching can kick in, thus it is more efficient.

Comment: `producer.send().get() should ensure ordering` - that answers. +1. The only place this can cause issues is when same producer is used across multiple threads.. but that goes for own analysis.

Answer (score 1):

No, you aren't guaranteed that messages will reach the related partition in the same order. Because the default value of "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection" config is 5.
If you didn't set 1, that going to try 5 times. And during this process you may lose the correct ranking.
Here is some reference;

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_max.in.flight.requests.per.connection

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_max.in.flight.requests.per.connection

Comment: but, i repeat, `producer.send(myRecord).get();` would not return untill sucess or failure. So how does inflight settings even matter for sync send. For a given producer, there is just one connection (right?) and that is used up by `.send().get()`.

Comment: No, there isn't any Synchronous structure between your application and Kafka Broker. Kafka broker handle the situation is internally. It has ISR list to check state of Leader and Follower partitions and every message has internal ID. The power of ISR list and message ID Kafka can determine which message committed or not committed. And with a retry mechanism it tries to send a message internally.

Comment: +1, i understand the `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` thing. But what i don't understand is when `.send().get()` blocks the thread - no other message can be attempted to deliver (unless the same producer is being used in multiple threads, in this situation i agree with Alan.) But in a single threaded situation - just doing `.send().get()` should ensure ordering.

Comment: Yeah, but what about multi instance? Single thread and multi instance at the same time? It couldn't do that. Because Kafka Broker works distributed. Multi partition, multi replication and also multi instance. Because of that it can't.

Comment: `what is a multi instance` in this context. Could you please elaborate. This is quite important for me to clarify.  But if I get it, a multi/different instance will run separately in it's own JVM and I don't think we can guarantee ordering between multi instances.

Comment: There are many technics that do this. But it's not our context. Kafka works distributed and also application can run on the multi instance. It's what I want to tell you. When you work with Kafka, forget Object-Oriented Programming or Functional Programming. It's distributed computing. Completely different from others.

Comment: right, some more additional mechanism should be in place for multi-instance, i am bothered about single instance for now.